# D3.js sunburst with multiple transitions

Tags: javascript, d3.js, transition, sunburst-diagram

I've been trying to modify the [zoomable sunburst](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4348373) example with a [size/count transition](http://strongriley.github.io/d3/ex/sunburst.html). [This fiddle shows my current situation](http://jsfiddle.net/emiguevara/7dr2q/).

I am stuck with one problem, namely, the combination of the two transformations does not produce the expected result. If you first click on a node to zoom-in, and then trigger the size/count transition, the nodes that should be shown are not correctly displayed.

My solution to this is to avoid triggering the size/count transition if the graph has been zoomed in: I reset the sunburst by simulating a click on the root node (to zoom out) and then changing size/count. This approach does work, but the visual effects are not very pleasing, [as you can see in my example](http://jsfiddle.net/emiguevara/7dr2q/). This is one of the two ways that I am testing: graph reset and size/count transition triggered by a radio button "change" event.

```
// Size/count radio-buttons with reset 1:
// dispatch both transitions on same event
d3.selectAll("input#size1, input#count1")
    .on("change", function() {
    // reset
    var root_node = d3.select("#root_node");
    var check = simulateClick(root_node[0][0]);
    // size/count
    if (check === true) {
        var change_value = this.value;
        path.data(partition.value(function(d) {
            if (change_value==="size") { return d.size; }
            else if (change_value==="count") { return 1; }
        }))
        .transition()
        .delay(400)
        .duration(600)
        .attrTween("d", arcTweenSwitch);
    }
});
```

Leaving aside implementation choices (trigger transitions on same event or on different events) and browser issues (tried Firefox and Chrome with different results), the problem is that two transitions seem to overlap. Using .delay() in the second one does not help.

The visual effect is that the second transition, instead of being a single smooth process, it seems to snap into the final stage at once, to then go back to the initial stage and playing the transition smoothly from the start.

Any pointers or advice warmly welcome... Thanks!